# How To Create A TCP Socket In VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, network-programming, tcplistener

I'm new in .NET programming. I was using sockets in VB6 as a component but in visual studio 2013 and VB.NET I don't know how to create a TCP Socket and listen for connections or send and receive messages. Can Any One Help Me In This Case?
thanks...

Comment: Please take a moment to review this carefully: [Ask]

Comment: [Read the documentation to start with](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w48w47c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).. :/ What your TCPSocket does and how it behaves is up to you.. Unless you have a very specific thing to ask, why don't you have a try first ?

Comment: These kinds of questions fits better in MSDN Forum. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=vbgeneral

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know how to create a TCP Socket

Look at the [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx), [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) and [`TcpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) classes in the [`System.Net.Sockets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx) namespace.

> listen for connections

Use `TcpListener`, calling one of its `Accept...()` methods ([`AcceptSocket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocket.aspx), [`AcceptSocketAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocketasync.aspx), [`AcceptTcpClient()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient.aspx), or [`AcceptTcpClientAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync.aspx)) as needed, depending on whether you want to use `Socket` or `TcpClient` objects to communicate with connected clients.

Use `TcpClient` to connect to a TCP server.

> send and receive messages

`TcpClient` has a [`GetStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx) method that returns a [`NetworkStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx).

Both `NetworkStream` and `Socket` have many reading/writing methods available, in blocking and asynchronous versions.